# What does Oracle CONCURRENCY_WAIT_TIME mean here?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jmeter

**Question**

- For simple select query takes longer with concurrency_wait_time, while the accessing table does not get inserted, updated, or deleted, is there any way I can do some kind of ***dirty read*** for the row in the specific table in Oracle?
- What does CONCURRENCY_WAIT_TIME mean here exactly? Can I guess that concurrency_wait_time would occur when accessing a same row(record) on a table from multiple sessions? Even when using read only?

**Situation**

I've been doing load tests on WEB and REST API server, found simple select query was taking time longer than expected.

**How it's tested**

- Jmeter from Desktop, 500 Concurrent POST request repeat 3 times and more

**Throughput Result**

- 30/sec when use 100 maxActive per instance
- 22/sec when use 200 maxActive per instance

**How to find slow query**

1. Spring AspectJ on Application to write method process time by @around annotation
2. Python script to analyze log to rank list methods with avg, min, max time
3. Found some DB select calls take too long (2~20 secs) which usually takes less than a second.
4. look up v$sqlarea to find slow query
5. **Top 4 queries were found with average time 2076 ms, which had about 1970 ms concurrency_wait_time**

[image]

> CONCURRENCY_WAIT_TIME : Concurrency wait time (in microseconds)

[Oracle V$SQLAREA Definition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2129.htm#REFRN30259)

Comment: It indicated the time that the server processes such LGWR, DBWn spends waiting for shared resources that have to be released by other server processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking for a bottleneck somewhere else as looking into:

> CONCURRENCY_WAIT_TIME : Concurrency wait time (in **microseconds**)

[Microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) is to one millionth of a second so it should not cause significant delays, it is internal Oracle synchronisation mechanism based on i.e. [latches](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_latches.htm), it is very simple and fast.

1. Ensure you have baseline OS health metrics monitoring in place for both your Java application server and database server, maybe the reason is banal lack of resources (CPU, RAM, Network or Disk). You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for this.
2. If your systems are not overloaded and you are still not happy with the processing time you could consider using Java Profilers like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) to find associated heavy methods.
3. Finally you can report the slow queries to DBAs so they could take a look into ways of queries optimization.